# Windows Forms in c# error

Tags: c#, forms, linqpad

For one of my projects, I need to write a program that shows a list of products with a check and or cross to the left of it. I have everything sorted except the forms part
I have come across this problem:

```
class Presentation
{
    static Form Window = new Form();
    static public void Configuration()
    {
        Window.Height = 800;
        Window.Width = 800;
        Window.Text = "Homework";

        Graphics draw = Window.CreateGraphics();

        Window.Paint += Window_Paint();

        Window.Show();
    }
    void Window_Paint(System.Object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        AnyOtherConfigurations(e);
    }
    static public void AnyOtherConfigurations(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8, 
        FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);
        Graphics draw = Window.CreateGraphics();
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow),x,y,80,80);
        draw.DrawRectangle(pen1, 0, 0, 90, 90);

    }
}
```

It gives me the error that says:

```
CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sender' of 'UserQuery.Presentation.Window_Paint(object, PaintEventArgs)'
CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler'
```

Can anyone suggest a reason why this might be happening and give me advice on how to fix it?

Comment: When you attach the event you are calling `Window_Paint` with zero arguments. Remove the parntheses: you do not want to call your handler at this point.

Comment: _Graphics draw = Window.CreateGraphics();_ and _Graphics draw = Window.CreateGraphics();_ Never do this! The result will not persist! Use the `e.Graphics`from the `PaintArgs` you already have!! - Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: You can test the persistance of your graphics by doing a Minimize/Maximize sequence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not write

```
Object.Event += Method();
```

but

```
Object.Event += Method;
```

instead.

The eventlistener wants a reference to the method to use the delegate, not to the returnvalue of the method itself. This explains your error.